# AngularJS ng-repeat in <tab> with ng-click to select the tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs

New to Angular and stuck for Tab selection. I am trying to use `<tabset>` and `<tab>` in angularJS and trying to call a function on ng-click when I hit a given TAB in my html. However, the method does not get invoked for some reason and I cannot print which tab I have selected. Here is the code:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeIn">
<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Submitted Deliveries</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="tabs-container">

            <tabset>
                <tab ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities" ng-click="vm.setTab(priority)" heading={{priority}}>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <delivery-directive></delivery-directive>
                    </div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

```js
 // Controller
 (function() {

'use strict';

angular.module('app.deliveries')
        .controller('DeliveriesController', DeliveriesController);

DeliveriesController.$inject = ['DeliveriesService', 'APP_CONFIG', '$interval', 'WorkspaceService'];

function DeliveriesController(deliveriesService, APP_CONFIG, $interval, workspaceService){

    var vm = this;
    vm.priorities = [];     // priorities are based the names of each workspace.
                            // So call the workspace end point from the workspaceService
                            // to get a list of all workspace. Then assign it to the priorities.

    vm.setTab = setTab;

    return init();

    function init(){
        workspaceService.getWorkspaces().then(function(workspaceResponse){
            vm.priorities = workspaceResponse;
        });
    }

  // This function does not get called and doesn't print anything
    function setTab(priority){
        console.log(priority);
    }
}

})();
```

Any suggestions what is missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using directives for tabset and tab such as angular-ui? If so, it is possible, that the dom nodes are getting moved around such that the thing you are putting the click on is not the same dom node you think you are clicking. For angular ui, the tabs have a select event handler you would use:

```
  <tabset>
      <tab ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities" select="vm.setTab(priority)" heading="{{priority}}">...</tab>
  </tabset>
```

NOTE: the latest version of angular-ui uses the uib- prefix, so that would now be

```
 <uib-tabset> 
     <uib-tab ng-repeat="priority in vm.priorities" select="vm.setTab(priority)" heading="{{priority}}">...</uib-tab>      
 </uib-tabset>
```

Comment: I tried that. Still no change in the outcome. Does not hit the `vm.setTab` method in my controller. And Yes, I am using custom directive. If you look below in the HTML< the `<delivery-directive>` is a custom directive

Comment: Are you using the angular-ui tab directive or is that something you made custom too?

Comment: angular-ui tab directive. Not using anything custom for the tab

Comment: hmm... any chance you could create fiddle or plunker showing the issue?